# Running Hibernate in clustered mode

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, microservices

I am planning to use Spring Data JPA along with Spring Boot with MySQL server. What are the challenges, considerations and best practices when considering running multiple instances of Spring Boot applications connecting to the DB.

As I understand from my knowledge, Hibernate should be considered when it completely owns the DB which is good in case of building monolith applications, but in case of running multiple instances (Microservices), how will each instance manage, update the state. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate can be used for Microservices when there is no local state maintained in any of the service in the application. The state could be using a hibernate second-level cache. When you want to go for a second-level cache make sure it is centralized and available for all the services in the application.

In fact this is a shared database pattern and using this pattern in Microservices architecture is absolutely fine.  This is discussed in Microservices architecture patterns https://microservices.io/patterns/data/shared-database.html

Comment: Since Hibernate using first level cache, will it cause any issues, if another instance updates the database before the first level cache changes are flushed to the database.

Comment: The first-level or session cache is scoped to transaction level. In case if two different services needs to update the same record, it is recommended to load the record with explicit lock. That would make the second caller to wait till the first one completes. This link has details concurrency control https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pessimistic-locking